# c# Reflection object[] issue

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, reflection, types

I am trying to use reflection to create object array of the type created from reflection like the folowing:

```
Client[] newArray = new Client[] {client1, client2};
```

I need to somehow get the `Client` object type to create the object so it can be passed through.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,
Rob

```
object clientObject = testAssembly.CreateInstance(".Testing_Automation.Client");        
Type client = testAssembly.GetType(".Testing_Automation.Client");

// Create Client Object Array
```

Passing to:

```
public Appointment(IEnumerable<Client> client, string time)
```

Comment: It's hard to cast into some type that you don't know at compile time. The IEnumerable<Client> conversion will be the trickier one to perform.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `Array.CreateInstance` method:

```
Array arr = Array.CreateInstance(client, lengthOfArray);
arr.SetValue(client1, 0); // Fill in the array...
arr.SetValue(client2, 1);
```

To get an `IEnumerable<Client>` from the array, you could use `(IEnumerable<Client>)arr` if you know the `Client` type at compile time. If you don't, which is likely, you should post more info about the possibilites of that method call.